# Is there a difference in meaning or correctness between “anderthalb” and “eineinhalb”?

Tags: word-choice

I remember years ago being taught that “one and a half” is *anderthalb*, and being corrected when I mistakenly used *eineinhalb*, but I’ve heard *eineinhalb* a few times recently on the radio.

Any significant difference? A regional thing, perhaps?

Comment: Interesting question, never thought about it until now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I learnt *anderthalb* when I was young. In the Duden, it's just a synonym for *eineinhalb*, so it doesn't seem to be regional. *Eineinhalb* is just regular, just like *Zweieinhalb* or *Dreieinhalb*. Or *Eineinviertel*, for that matter. Both forms are correct.

From the Grimm:

> anderthalb, sesquialter, einundeinhalb. wie man dritthalb 2, vierthalb 3, fünfthalb 4 u. s. w. mit der ordinalzahl bildet, ist auch anderhalb vollkommen richtig, und die meinung, dasz der zählende auf die mitte oder hälfte von 1 zu 2 gelange, das andere (zweite) halb erreicht sei; auch heiszt es mhd. anderhalp (Ben. 1, 614b). als sich allmälich das gefühl für die ordinalität des wortes ander schwächte, begann man t von vierthalb, fünfthalb nachzuahmen und, gleich als gelte anderte für ander, anderthalb zu schreiben, wie nun allgemein üblich geworden ist. anderthalb ellen. 2 Mos. 25, 10, 17. 23; anderthalb pfund, anderthalb meilen; mein vatter hett nur einen arm, so hab ich anderthalben. Fischart Garg. 94b; seiner natur nach steht dies halb immer im sg.

If I understand correctly, it means that you get to the middle/half between 1 and 2, to the other half (*andere Hälfte/anderhalb*). The t was added in similarity to other ordinals, like in *dritthalb*, which seems to mean two and a half (the third half). These expressions are not used anymore today, I think, at least never heard them.

Comment: "anderthalb" is widely used in Austria. At least colloquially.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: If I was unclear: I meant that dritthalb, vierthalb etc. are not used anymore. *Anderthalb* is still used widely.

Comment: Just to add: As far as I remember, *andert* used to mean *zweit*, hence *anders - the (second) possibility*. It's still used as the ordinal number in Danish.

Answer (score 4):

I learnt *eineinhalb* when I was young and that was before I studied mathematics. But I have no problems with people using *anderthalb*.

I can't say [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anderthalb,%20eineinhalb&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=8&smoothing=3)  what ngram exactly tells, perhaps that people prefer to use number symbols today or that everyday items are manufactured in sizes, that needs less fractions. Did you ever try to warm up 1 1/2 meals in your microwave oven?

In any case the usage of both forms tends to be equal today.

Comment: pretty equal http://www.google.com/trends?q=anderthalb+%2C+eineinhalb&ctab=0&geo=all&geor=all&date=all&sort=0

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there are regional differences, but here (Upper Austria) *anderthalb* sounds somewhat dated or like dialect speech. Good choice for written text would be *eineinhalb* or 1½.

Answer (score 3):

"Eineinhalb" is clumsy, hard to speak and hard to read.
Hence, the better choice is "anderthalb".

Answer (score 2):

To me "eineinhalb" feels somewhat more formal than "anderthalb". I would prefer "anderthalb" when speaking, while in writing I would use either depending on the context.